# Держать соединение чат+браузер на телефоне

Tags: javascript, ajax, чат

Держать соединение чат+браузер на телефоне.
У меня есть чат, который работает на php и JS. Захожу с телефона - всё хорошо, но если я блокирую экран, а браузер не закрываю, то скрипт думает, что я закрыл страницу, и меня выкидывает из чата.
И другой пример: есть радио на каком нибудь сайте, я включаю музыку, нажимаю блокировку экрана, а музыка продолжает играть!
Вопрос: Каким образом можно оставаться в чате при блокировке экрана? Будет это JavaScript или jQuery роли не играет...

Comment: Скорее всего никак, телефон принудительно убивает неактивные вкладки. А вот именно для музыки сделано исключение

Comment: Но при разблокировке скажем через минут 5 - Я разблокирую экран и опять возвращаюсь в чат ничего не делая... (таймаут у меня на час прописан). Но пользователи меня не видят, так как думают, что я с концами... Или может как вариант привязать фоновую музыку в окне чата, которая будет играть нон-стоп? Или всёравно оборвёт соединение???